# Trying to identify 80s or older Sci Fi movie with a "Citadel", a robot, and a sound paralysing rotating crystal

Tags: story-identification, movie

Requesting help with identifying a science fiction movie that I saw once as a kid during eighties (so it could be older than that). I remember just a few scenes, and I am not certain about the accuracy of these descriptions.

The only scenes I remember were happening inside some control room that is located inside a house or a castle of sorts, and which was translated as "citadel" in Croatian. Considering "citadel" is not a Croatian word, I suspect it may have been called "citadel" in the original language as well. (I assume the film was in English, but I am not sure.)

There was a robot in the movie.  Humanoid in shape though bulky, hands are flexible (like tubes), not very intelligent, not aggressive, somewhat slow in motion.

The most recognizable feature for me was a "weapon" of sorts.  It was located in the middle of some room (like a control room).  It consists of something like a crystal on a rotating axis, and when it gets to a high rotation speed, it produces a loud sound that paralyses any humans in the room.  There was a helmet that protects against that sound; it was transparent like glass, hemispherical in shape, and it could be just placed on the head to protect against the sound.  I remember a scene where one male character puts the helmet on and turns the crystal rotation on, to paralyze the other male in the room.  I think that happened near the end of the movie, and that the "attack" was unsuccessful; the second male managed to wrestle the helmet off the first one, and turn the sound (crystal) off.

The last scene I think I remember is the "citadel" being destroyed in some kind of seismic event, an earthquake or a volcano or such.

Unfortunately, it is not much, but that's all I can vaguely remember 
 (I've been Googleing for it for years, no luck thus far.  I'll appreciate any help!)

Comment: Did the robot look like [this](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wally_Cox_Lost_in_Space_1966.JPG)?

Comment: Hmm, it could be, fits the profile. I think the hands were of just this type, like flexible tubes.  I dont remember the head.  I am not certain, but it could be, yes.

Comment: @user24445: You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark. :) You can accept either mine or thepropergerman. I got your message on my blog, but we do prefer it if you accept it on the site.

Comment: I could see the Dupe go either way, but I prefer a bit the one that's been explicitly accepted via the system, rather than by comment.

Answer (score 11):

Try *[The Shape of Things to Come](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079894/)* with Jack Palance. I was just listening to a podcast mentioning Jack and recalled a childhood memory from Germany of him wearing a clear plastic bucket on his head in an old sci-fi movie.

Comment: THIS IS IT!! WONDERFUL!! :-) WOW!! After 30+ years! This is great! So happy!! :-) After so many years, I though it just won't happen. 

This now almost calls for some long-term-memory experiment. The one and the only time I saw it was in mid-1980s, thirty years ago; no VCR, no reruns. To measure how much the memory faded. I'd say not much, the scenes visually really match my recollections. :-)

"thepropergerman": Thank you very much! :-) And all other for the great suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds very much like you're describing the film *[Logan's Run](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074812/)*.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not "Logan's run".  This rotating crystal seems to me quite unique.  While searching, I've seen something vaguely similar in "Dr Who" (forgot which episode); it could be one of "Dr Who" episodes by the feel, but not sure..

Comment: This looks like star crash

Comment: I just saw "Star Crash" - unfortunately it is not the one, but it has a lot of similarities (scenes, behavior, technology, that head cover helmet looks quite similar, and the robot,..), and the general feeling is right.  Do you know any other movies like this one, suggestions?  I'll watch each such suggestion, one by one, till I find it.  :-)  Thank you!

Comment: Specifically that scene where the item in the control room ("crystal"-I call it) is rotating, and it produces a sound that paralyses the people in the room; that is the scene that I remember most vividly.  The person in the control room with the glass helmet on is not affected by the sound.  Something like that.  The effect of "paralysing sound" is similar like in "Star Crash" at 3:00 timestamp.  The "glass helmet" is similar to this one: http://images.linnlive.com/1e037c81da387d8e4d1c2557d0a46f2b/dc4a218b-8ffd-4b0c-bca9-4ce1d2bfd1ab.jpg

Comment: I'll be grateful for a list with any potential candidate movies; I'll happily watch all of them one by one till I find it.  :-)  "Star Crash" felt like it might be it till the very end.  :-)

Comment: Going back to Logan's run for a moment, does [this](http://www.virginmedia.com/images/robots-logan.jpg) look at all familiar?

Answer (score 4):

*[The Shape of Things to Come](http://www.phathom.com/2011/05/crazy-sci-fi-shape/)*, starring Jack Palance as the villain.

[image: The Shape of Things to Come film poster]

There is a "Citadel – a massive tower controlled by Omus and his robot minions" in the film as well as a robot with the flexible arms, Sparky. I haven't found a picture of the weapon, but the description from Wikipedia is:

> Omus refuses to listen and then dons a transparent helmet where he shows Caball another creation – a spinning disco ball-like device that drives Caball mad with pain and eventually kills him.

Another site described the device as looking like a "spinning bundt cake" and notes that Jason was able to snatch the helmet from Omus and protect himself.

And indeed, there is a cataclysm at the end:

> The robot frenzy however, overloads critical systems and explosions begin to rip through the Citadel. Sparks escapes in the cargo ship, while the others make it back to the Starstreak and lift off. They leave Omus sitting in his control room while everything explodes around him. The destruction of the Citadel eventually causes the whole planet to explode.