# Film with spacecraft departing for a mission to the moon, stating something like "more bombs for New London"

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I am trying to ID a film. Very probably a TV movie. US made, live action, seen on British TV late 80s early 90s and almost certainly, from the hair styles I recall, made in the 80s. Most likely broadcast on Channel 4.

No actors that I can identify leading me to think it's pretty low budget.

Specifically remember a line of dialogue like "more bombs for new London" as spacecraft depart the moon on a mission. The name of the city may easily be misremembered. Could just as easily be New Washington or New... something.

SFX was all physical models. No CGI. The aesthetic was Star Wars/ Original Battlestar Galactica, so very gray looking ship with lots of hatches, pipework and vents like the surface of a Star Destroyer.

I don't recall flight helmets or details of the pilot's uniform. I do recall that the ship was not a fighter and may even be a civilian ship.

Very uncertain on the plot but seemed to be earth being threatened and attacked by an evil overlord from his secret base on another planet. The line of dialogue I recall was spoken by the pilot of a spaceship leaving the moon. The mission was to infiltrate the planet/base where the bombs directed towards earth were being launched from.

I may be conflating two separate films but I think there was a scene later on, as they key character (and possibly the female love interest - there always is one of these things) approached the enemy base across a wide grassy expanse of land and the main villain appeared as a giant rotating hologram in the sky to give a sort of "nothing can stop my evil pan from succeeding" type speech.

Beyond that I really don't recall any more except that it was a small cast of central characters.

Comment: Can you remember any other details? What colour were the uniforms, what did the flight helmets look like, what did the spaceships look like? _Anything_ about the plot or story?

Comment: So there was a war between Moon and Earth? Was they really bombing some city?

Comment: "evil overboard"...? Did you mean overlord?

Comment: @LogicDictates Maybe he needed his evil pan to stay afloat.

Comment: @LogicDictates Ha ha ha ha !!!!!! yes evil overlord!!! thank you autocorrect!!!!

Comment: An Evil Overbaker apparently

Comment: Are you sure it's a movie and not a episode of a serie? like space 1999 ?

Comment: @MarcelDevG definitely not Space 1999. It could be a pilot for an unmade show show or a show that did not get broadcast in the UK though.

Comment: Comment-accepted at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52840/trying-to-identify-80s-or-older-sci-fi-movie-with-a-citadel-a-robot-and-a-so/79257#79257

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite by chance I find I can answer my own question. Stumbling around on Youtube earlier today I discovered clips of a 1979 film called The Shape of Things to Come.

A great many things were misremembered on my part but

It features a colony on the Moon called New Washington.

Low budget, all physical models, with a Star Wars/Battlestar Galactica feel.

The scene I describe with characters crossing a grassy expanse and talking with a giant projection of the big bad is present and correct and occurs at 1 hour 14 minutes in this YouTube post.

a full synopsis and details of cast and production is available on wikipedia here...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._G._Wells%27_The_Shape_of_Things_to_Come

One of the commenters asked if I was misremembering Space 1999. I was certain I was not, as this shows but I was surprised to learn that this film does feature Barry Morse who did appear in Space 1999.

Comment: Not to be confused with the 1936 movie *Things to Come* with screenplay by H. G. Wells. First sci-fi movie I ever saw, in a double feature with *The Man Who Could Work Miracles*.